# API Django Rest Framework on Cloud Run shutting down

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-run

I have implemented an API DRF on Cloud Run. The Dockerfile is the following:

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Cloud Run logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files to disc (equivalent to python -B option)
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE True

ARG REQFILE=base.txt
ENV REQFILE ${REQFILE}

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# Copying this separately prevents re-running pip install on every code change.
COPY requirements/*.txt ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install -r ./${REQFILE}

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

It is the same as described in the documentation : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-django#6

But since a few days, without any significative change on my code, I have the following errors :
[image]

Because of that, some query on my API are really slow (>60sec). Usually, they are <500ms.

What is the cause of these shutting down ?

Comment: It looks like you have a bug in your code that causes a server crash. Do you have more logs?

Comment: The bugs and errors are usually catch by the google cloud error reporting. And these type of logs only appears 5 days ago : it did not coincide with a push in prod.

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce this behavior in docker locally?

Comment: I tried this weekend to reproduce the bug on local, without success. It seems that since Saturday, the bug is not present anymore. The only difference was that on Cloud build, the last build was blocked (normal behavior, a bug detected in CD).
I pushed a commit without noticeable difference.
I think the problem was linked to Cloud Run infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing my Docker locally without identifying any errors or bugs, I came to the conclusion that the problem was due to the cold starts of cloud run.
Even though I implemented months ago a solution (periodic queries on Cloud Run with Cloud Scheduler), the problem was present.

I tried today to [implement a minimal number](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances) of instance, currently one.
The number of really high latency queries drops to 0.

The cost does not seem really high (I will comment the price at the end of the month, I expect something like 14€), and honestly, to get rid of this problem, I would have pay easily the double.

Answer (score 1):

Given the situation, it is very likely this was related to the [Cloud Run Incident #20004](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-run/20004):

> `Oct 29, 2020 13:12`: We are investigating an issue with Cloud Run deployments failing globally starting at Thursday, 2020-10-29 12:45 US/Pacific.

> `Oct 29, 2020 13:40`: Diagnosis: New deployments to Cloud Run will fail globally.

> `Oct 29, 2020 14:16`: The issue with Cloud Run deployments failing globally has been resolved for all affected projects as of Thursday, 2020-10-29 14:07 US/Pacific.

It is well worth to take a look into the [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/) to check whether there are/were any incidents on each product.

Comment: I checked in fact at that moment, but I thought it was not linked (it is deployment at fault). But you are right, it may be a correlation.